# How to activate GitHub Copilot on a remote Ubuntu server (SSH) showing "Extension activation failed: Copilot not available in your location"?

Tags: github-copilot

GitHub Copilot work correctly on my local computer (I have individual subscription).

But When I try to connect to remote host (SSH Ubuntu 22.04), GitHub Copilot show below error

```
[INFO] [auth] [2023-08-30T07:02:59.734Z] Invalid copilot token: missing token: 403 
[ERROR] [default] [2023-08-30T07:02:59.738Z] GitHub Copilot could not connect to server. Extension activation failed: "At this time, Copilot is not available in your location. You are currently logged in as soroshsabz."
```

How to resolve this problem?